# Unexpect Token 'done' in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm ver unfamiliar with writing shell scripts but I am trying to write a script that checks whether a file is currently open before executing a command. I'm getting the following error

```
 ./Script.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./Script.sh: line 9: `done'
```

As a bonus I don't know that the `"|"` operator does I've found a few shell syntax sites but since its a single character searching for its purpose has been difficult.

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m -r -e create "sunshine" | while read NEWFILE
do
        if [ lsof | grep NEWFILE ]; then
                echo "found something";
        else
                aws s3 sync sunshine s3://turnaround-sunshine/
done
```

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if`/`else` is missing a `fi` at the end.

`|` creates a **pipe** between two commands with the output of the first fed as input to the second. The second pipe in the `if` statement should not have square brackets, by the way; and `grep NEWFILE` should be `grep "$NEWFILE"`:

```
if lsof | grep "$NEWFILE"; then
```

Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch these types of errors.